# exercises for Euclid's Elements

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Can you suggest some books with exercises related to Euclid's Elements, or to Euclidean Geometry, as an aid to an undergraduate course on Euclidean Geometry and its history? I need exercises that involve not complicated proofs.

Comment: You can find some on archive.org. Just search "euclid exercises," or something related. Here's one example: https://archive.org/details/euclidbookwithn00euclgoog. Also you can just look for copies of the elements and sometimes they put exercises at the end of each book for schools back in the day. hope that helps, I'm looking for some good exercises as well

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should refer " A sequel to Euclid's elements' first six books" by John Casey, for plane euclidean geometry.